# Swift and Amazon Web Services

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I am building a new application and I am now starting to build the backend.

I am writing in swift and I am having issues with the sample code.

becuase I have an existing app I am trying to copy and paste the code from the sample project to my actual application. I linked all of the binaries and libraries to make it look identical to the sample. I have updated the plist by dragging in the AWS and Security portions. I have made all of the supporting.swift files and have matched up the app delagate to be the same.

EveryTime I run it, it Fails.. With the error code of **"no such module "MobileHubHelper"**

I have imported the framework of MobileHubHelper and it just wont work. I have also made sure it was linked as well.

I am getting extremely frustrated with this whole process, and there is not a lot of good information out there. I have taken everything out of my app and rebuilt a new app in the hub, re-downloaded the samples and did the process over and over and every time I get the same error...

Can Someone Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

I totally feel your pain because I've been playing with the AWS Mobile Hub too and am having a tough time accomplishing anything. After a bunch of tries (and getting the same error as you) I was able to make a single view application with one button that logs in to Facebook. So far it doesn't do anything else, but I can show you how I linked the libraries and hopefully it will work for you too. Xcode seems really particular about how I linked the libraries. This was the only way that seemed to work.

It sounds like you already have the `MySampleApp` from the AWS Mobile Hub? Assuming that, use the Mac Finder to go into the "MySampleApp" folder so you're looking at this:

[image]

I then opened my new `AWSTest` project in Xcode and dragged first the `AmazonAWS` folder to my test project, right in between the Project and the top-level folder:

[image]

I selected the drag options like this:

[image]

I then dragged the `SDK` folder in also, right above the `AmazonAWS` folder:

[image]

At this point you should see them both at the top like this:

[image]

The `Embedded Binaries` section will still be blank as shown below, but the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section should show a bunch of the AWS stuff without having to do anything. The previous times when I couldn't get it to work, I was adding these by clicking the `+` button; for some reason doing it with the drag method and having them appear automatically seems better.

[image]

Now add the embedded binaries by clicking the `+` button. Add the exact same binaries that are listed in the `MySampleApp` binaries section. You should see them right there as soon as the window opens, without having to navigate elsewhere:

[image]

In the Swift code, be sure to add `import AWSMobileHubHelper` at the top, then try doing something basic like this. I attached this code to a button, so when you click the button, it'll open the Facebook login screen. I also had to add settings to `info.plist`, of course, but hopefully these steps will at least enable you to get past the "no such module AWSMobileHubHelper" error.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate all of your help... I will tell you I got so sick of trying and trying, and having little to no good resources available to help me with AWS I left. I went and checked out a couple different BaAs and sided with Firebase. I already have a substantial amount of progress and there is a ton of info including youtube videos and all to help. Firebase seems to do all of the things that I need maybe not as powerful as AWS but for what I am making it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Interesting! The fact that you've already made more progress with Firebase seems to be a sign that maybe it's designed better. You've piqued my curiosity about it.

Comment: There is a lot of info out there for it... much easier overall.. the cocoa pods were kind of a pain but all in all I'm happy with what I'm doing